# Best practices: Namespace or resources for admin interface dashboard Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, resources, namespaces

I will build a admin interface for my aplication back-end.

I am using Mongoid, and I want to know What is the best for make my own Backend Interface.

I can not use **active_admin** because it does not works for **mongoid** odm.

I have in my routes:

```
devise_for :admins
namespace :admin do
 resources :categories
 resources: users
 resources: posts
 .
 .
 .
end
```

I have in my controller categories for example:

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!   # assuming you're using devise
   def index
    #etc.
  end
end
```

Its better use namespace or resources?

**which is best practice to create an interface for the administrator with others odms or database without using gems as active_admin, rails_admin, typus...etc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use namespace but remember this:

**Do not use the same word as namespace and resources**

```
namespace :admin
  resources :categories
end
```

is fine as long as you don't have a model resource named admin or admins. Otherwise, you will have a hard time debugging or constructing the proper routes( admin_foo_bar_path, can refer either admin namespace or admin resource, which confuses both you and rails ).